# "Member not found" - jQuery not working in MSIE but works in Chrome -

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, google-chrome, windows-server-2012

I have an `MVC4 .NET` web app which performs without `issue/errors` while debugging.  I published the solution to a folder and deployed the app files to a web server (Windows Server 2012).

The application loads and runs correctly however on one page where I have a jQuery autocomplete, an error is thrown while using the browser debugger in MSIE 11 and the auto complete does not work.

** **There are no errors when the page is viewed in Google Chrome**, nor are there errors in Visual Studio.

What could be causing this?

Here's the error thrown on page load in IE only

> **member not found:**

[Here's a larger image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4mEK.jpg)

[image: error in debug]

Comment: could you post your autocomplete part of the application?

Comment: What version of jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following line to the `<head>` tag of my `_Layout.cshtml` page and now the page loads with out JS errors and the jQuery autocomplete is functioning correctly:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >
```

** How would I have known to add this?  What would one research to ensure these type of meta tag is not overlooked in the future?

Thanks!

Comment: This is my exact problem, and this solution worked for me! Although I have no idea what this is doing.